# The value of $0^0$ said here to depend on whether $0\in N$ or $0\in R$. Any other instance of such a distinction?

Tags: calculus, real-numbers

> According to some Calculus textbooks, $0^0$ is an "indeterminate
> form." When evaluating a limit of the form $0^0$, then you need to know
> that limits of that form are called "indeterminate forms", and that
> you need to use a special technique such as L'Hopital's rule to
> evaluate them. Otherwise, $0^0 = 1$ seems to be the most useful choice
> for $0^0$. This convention allows us to extend definitions in different
> areas of mathematics that otherwise would require treating $0$ as a
> special case....
>
> This means that depending on the context where $0^0$ occurs, you might wish to substitute it with 1, indeterminate or undefined/nonexistent.

Source: "What is $0^ 0?$", [Math FAQ's](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ealopez-o/math-faq/mathtext/node14.html), University of Waterloo

My question: The above seems to be suggesting that the value of $0^0$ depends on whether $0\in N$ or $0\in R$. Does this make sense on any level? Does this represent a consensus among mathematicians, and if so, are there any other known instance in which such a distinction is made for $0\in R$ and $0\in N$ or any other number that is both a real and a natural number?

Comment: Well, $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ for all natural numbers  $x$, but not for all real numbers.  On the other hand, I'd say $0^0=1$ in $\mathbb R$ as well as $\mathbb N$. The business about "indeterminate form" just means that the function $x^y$ (or just $0^y$) is discontinuous at $x=y=0$ (or just $y=0$), so you shouldn't use $0^0=1$ to evaluate $\lim_{z\to0} 0^{f(z)}$ when $\lim_{z=0}f(z)=0$.

Comment: "*Is there any other known instance in which such a distinction is made...*" you should know that $0!=1$ that $\sum\limits_{i\in\emptyset} a_i=0$ as well as $\prod\limits_{i\in\emptyset} a_i = 1$ (*referred to as the emptysum and the emptyproduct respectively*).

Comment: @AndreasBlass But $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ for all real numbers that are also natural numbers.

Comment: Your link says limits of the form $0^0$ require special techniques; it doesn't say that the value of $0^0$ should be interpreted differently when $0\in\mathbb R$. Also I'm not convinced that the convention discussed there is universally accepted; I think when such a convention is assumed it would usually be noted.

Comment: @stewbasic It seems to me that the author is suggesting that $0^0$ is an "indeterminate form" for $0\in R$ and that $0^0=1$ for $0\in N.$ Is this not a widely held consensus?

Comment: Being an indeterminate form does not mean being undefined, for what it is worth.

Comment: I'm somewhat repeating @Andreas Blass's comment. Under the convention being discussed, the expression $0^0$ is just a real number equal to $1$. However a limit $\lim f(x)^{g(x)}$ is said to have "indeterminate form $0^0$" if $\lim f(x)=\lim g(x)=0$. This is a statement about the limit, not about the expression.

Comment: So, being an indeterminate form means that computer programs using floating point values should leave $0.0^{0.0}$ undefined, but that's because all such values are really ranges, and a discontinuity makes it a bad idea to use the value $1$. But floating point numbers are not real numbers, really, they are number ranges.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Actually WP says most common languages evaluate pow(0.0, 0.0) to 1.0: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Zero_to_the_power_of_zero

Comment: @stewbasic In the same article IIUC, the limit is path dependent. The limit can be any positive value depending on the path chosen. In that sense then, $0^0$ is indeterminate on R. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Continuous_exponents

Comment: As an aside, a similar  sort of thing is that you probably define $\sqrt[3]{-1} = -1$... until you consider complex numbers, at which point you probably use $\sqrt[3]{-1} = (1+\sqrt{-3})/2$ instead.

Comment: @DanChristensen Yes, the limit is path dependent. This means "limit expressions of the form $0^0$ are indeterminate", not "$0^0$ is indeterminate". This is consistent with your WP link which says "the resulting expression does not determine the original limit"; that is, even if we take $0^0=1$, this doesn't determine $\lim f(x)^{g(x)}$.

Comment: @stewbasic What then to make of: "This means that depending on the context where 0^0 occurs, you might wish to substitute it with 1, indeterminate or undefined/nonexistent."

Comment: @DanChristensen fair point, that paragraph does seem to advocate $0^0$ being dependent on whether $0\in\mathbb N$ or $0\in\mathbb R$. However I think that convention is uncommon. Moreover it's inconsistent with the convention I described above, which other parts of the article seem to advocate.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any other known instance in which such a distinction is made for $0\in R$ and $0\in N$ or any other number that is both a real and a natural number?

I don't read that distinction as being made into the linked page. I guess
it may be referring to the following paragraph, but it's not clear from the context whether that's a quote from elsewhere, or author's own statement of opinion. Interestingly enough (though maybe unsurprising), google finds multiple hits for the exact same phrase, though none wiser as to its ultimate source.

> As a rule of thumb, one can say that $0^0 = 1$, but $0.0^{0.0}$ is undefined, meaning that when approaching from a different direction there is no clearly predetermined value to assign to $0.0^{0.0}$

My own take on this is that I would find it incredibly confusing to see a math function $f(x,y)$ defined in such a way that the value of $f(0,0)$ depends on whether $0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ vs. $\in \mathbb{R}$ vs. $\in \mathbb{C}$ etc.

As a concrete example of where the convention $0^0=1$ is applied regardless of any integers vs. reals distinction (and the exception $0^0=\text{undefined}$ is applied likewise), see the widespread IEEE-754 floating-point standard family of [pow functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Operations_generating_NaN):

> The standard has alternative functions for powers:
>
> - The standard **pow** function and the integer exponent **pown** function define $0^0$, $1^{\infty}$, and $\infty^0$ as $1$.
> - The **powr** function defines all three indeterminate forms as invalid operations and so returns $\text{NaN}$.

The latter **powr** function is "*not widely available*", according to [oeis](http://oeis.org/wiki/The_special_case_of_zero_to_the_zeroth_power).